# How do differences between total calculations occur in long format using Stata

Tags: time-series, stata

Sometimes, I use a somewhat overblown approach to create variables in Stata when I am working with time series or panel data in the long shape: I am creating many new variables in the wide data shape while actually maintaining the long data shape. Having such an overblown dataset there are two different ways to create a total variable which sums these variables up using either `egen = rowtotal(varlist)` or `by varlist: egen = total(exp)`. However, using `compare` shows that these two ways have minimally different results. How do these differences occur?

Here is a working example:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
drop if year < 1950

*** Totals using new variables in wide data shape for each year ***
gen invest50 = invest if year==1950
gen invest51 = invest if year==1951
gen invest52 = invest if year==1952
gen invest53 = invest if year==1953
gen invest54 = invest if year==1954
bysort company: replace invest50 = invest50[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1950
bysort company: replace invest51 = invest51[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1951
bysort company: replace invest52 = invest52[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1952
bysort company: replace invest53 = invest53[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1953
gsort company -year
bysort company: replace invest51 = invest51[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1951
bysort company: replace invest52 = invest52[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1952
bysort company: replace invest53 = invest53[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1953
bysort company: replace invest54 = invest54[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1954
sort company year
egen totin1 = rowtotal(invest50 invest51 invest52 ///
    invest53 invest54) 

*** Totals using variables in long data shape and by-option ***
bysort company (year): egen totin2 = total(invest)

desc tot*
compare totin1 totin2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical precision is the issue here. Use `double` to get "precise" results:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
drop if year < 1950

keep company invest year

*** Totals using new variables in wide format for each year ***
gen double invest50 = invest if year==1950
gen double invest51 = invest if year==1951
gen double invest52 = invest if year==1952
gen double invest53 = invest if year==1953
gen double invest54 = invest if year==1954

bysort company: replace invest50 = invest50[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1950

bysort company: replace invest51 = invest51[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1951

bysort company: replace invest52 = invest52[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1952

bysort company: replace invest53 = invest53[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]>1953

gsort company -year

bysort company: replace invest51 = invest51[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1951

bysort company: replace invest52 = invest52[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1952

bysort company: replace invest53 = invest53[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1953

bysort company: replace invest54 = invest54[_n-1] ///
    if company[_n]==company[_n-1] & year[_n]<1954

sort company year

egen double totin1 = rowtotal(invest50 invest51 invest52 ///
    invest53 invest54) 

*** Totals using variables in long format and by-option ***

bysort company (year): egen double totin2 = total(invest)

desc tot*
compare totin1 totin2
```

The results is

```
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
totin1          double %10.0g                 
totin2          double %10.0g                 

. compare totin1 totin2

                                        ---------- difference ----------
                            count       minimum      average     maximum
------------------------------------------------------------------------
totin1=totin2                  50
                       ----------
jointly defined                50             0            0           0
                       ----------
total                          50
```

See http://blog.stata.com/2011/06/17/precision-yet-again-part-i/ and references therein.

Comment: Am I really running into the old float format issue? Damn. At least I know by now, that the overblown first variant rounded way too often in comparison with the short second variant.

Comment: `float` is a variable (storage type), not a format. The word "format" is heavily overloaded here. I suggest talking about wide or long data shape or data structure, although misunderstandings on this point seem rare. (Neverthless `long` is also a storage type in Stata.)

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the clarification, I have edited my question but I cannot edit my comment anymore.

Comment: I think you need to spell out how your question is now different and what does not satisfy you about Roberto Ferrer's answer. In particular, you don't summarize what you think your code is showing.

Comment: The question has not really changed, as the _revision history_ shows. The original poster has only made a change in terminology.